# Iterating through hash of hashes converts elements into Array

Tags: ruby

I'm working on processing a response of a Webhook from GitHub. The response contains a hash `web_hook_response` that looks like this

```
{:commits=>
  {:modified=>
    ["public/en/landing_pages/dc.json",
     "draft/en/landing_pages/careers/ac123.json"]
  }
}
```

Now I have a function that processes this hash.

```
 modified_or_deleted_files = []
 web_hook_response[:commits].map do |commit|
     modified_or_deleted_files << commit[:removed] << commit[:modified]
 end
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I tried to find out the value of `commit` when it's inside the map block and this is what got printed

```
[:modified,
 ["public/en/landing_pages/dc.json",
  "draft/en/landing_pages/careers/ac123.json"]]
```

Why is the `modified` hash converting into an array of a symbol and an array inside the map block? I can't explain why this is happening. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: When you give an example, please: 1) show the expected output (as a Ruby object); 2) make the example as short as possible without oversimplifying (you might have written, for example, `...:modified => ["public", "draft"]`) and 3) assign a variable to each input (e.g., `hook = { :commits =>....}` (so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and also to facilitate cutting-and-pasting).

Comment: Can you please give the GitHub URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

This is the hash you are given (simplified slightly).

```
web_hook_response = {
  :commits => { :modified => ["public", "draft"] }
}
```

It has one key-value pair, the key being `:commits` and the value being the hash

```
{ :modified => ["public", "draft"] }
```

which itself has one key (`:modified`) and one value (`["public", "draft"]`).

**Error**

Try this (with my definition of `web_hook_response`):

```
web_hook_response[:commits].map do |commit|
  puts "commit = #{commit}"
  modified_or_deleted_files << commit[:removed] << commit[:modified] # line 397
end
  # commit = [:modified, ["public", "draft"]]
  # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    from (irb):397:in `[]'
    from (irb):397:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):395:in `each'
    from (irb):395:in `map'
```

Note that `commit` equals a key-value pair from the hash `web_hook_response[:commits]`. As you see, an attempt is made to compute

```
commit[:removed]
  #=> [:modified, ["public", "draft"]][:removed]
```

which is the *syntactic sugar* form of the conventional expression

```
[:modified,  ["public", "draft"]].[](:removed)
```

Since `[:modified,  ["public", "draft"]]` is an array, [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is an instance method of the class `Array`. (Yes, it's a funny name for a method, but that's what it is.) As explained in its doc, the method's argument must be an integer, namely, the index of an element of the array that is to to be returned. Therefore, when Ruby discovers that the argument is a symbol (`:removed`), she raises the exception, *"no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"*.

**Computing `modified_or_deleted_files`**

Given the keys `:commits` and `:modified` we may extract the hash

```
h = web_hook_response[:commits]
  #=> { :modified=>["public", "draft"] }
```

and from that extract the array

```
a = h[:modified]
  #=> ["public", "draft"]
```

We would normally chain these two operations to obtain the array in one statement.

```
web_hook_response[:commits][:modified]
  #=> ["public", "draft"]
```

It appears you wish to simply set the value of the variable `modified_or_deleted_files` to this array, so simply write the following.

```
modified_or_deleted_files = web_hook_response[:commits][:modified]
  #=> ["public", "draft"]
```

Comment: commits has 2 keys. :modified and :removed. we have to push both the arrays to modified_or_deleted_files.

Comment: @Ajith, I don't understand. `:commits` is a symbol and `web_hook_response[:commits]` is a hash having a single key-value pair.

Comment: he is trying to push commit[:removed] as well in the question. so i meant probably his hash structure is something like this web_hook_response = {
  :commits => {
    :modified => ["public", "draft"],
    :removed => ["file1", "file2"]
  }
}

Comment: @Ajith, you may have telepathic powers (and you may be correct regardless!) but the definition of `web_hook_response` is unambiguous.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ajith is right. The commits key was supposed to have an array instead of a hash. I tested it with wrong data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`web_hook_response[:commits]` is a hash, not an array, so when you call `map` on it, the block parameter `commit` gets key-value pairs, which are arrays of size 2.

I think what you need is to concatenate 2 arrays. You can

```
modified_or_deleted_files = web_hook_response[:commits].slice(:modified, :removed).values.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `:commits` is a hash. When iterating through hashes, you usually use two block arguments, one for the key and one for the value, for example:

```
{ :foo => 'bar' }.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} = #{value}"
}
# outputs:
# foo = bar
```

When you only use one block argument you will get a key-value pair in an array:

```
{ :foo => 'bar' }.each do |pair|
  puts pair.inspect
end
# outputs:
# [:foo, "bar"]
```

In your example you could just do:

```
commits = web_hook_response[:commits]
modified_or_deleted_files = Array(commits[:removed]) + Array(commits[:modified])
```

(The `Array(...)` is used to avoid an error if `commits[:removed]` or `commits[:modified]` is `nil`. `Array(nil)` returns an empty array, `Array(an_array)` returns the array)

Or if you want to get fancy with the enumerators, iterators and such:

```
modified_or_deleted_files = web_hook_response[:commits].
  values_at(:modified, :removed). 
  compact. 
  reduce(:+)
```